# Postgres 9.6 Find distinct time periods and count of records within a certain time range

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I have a table that looks like below:

```
CREATE TABLE "time_records" (
  startdate timestamp,
  starttime timestamp,
  endtime timestamp,
  timesheetid int,
  servicestate int,
  recordcount int
);
```

There will be some overlaps within a day for the same timesheetid and servicestate. I have a count (recordcount) of the underlying records for each time range.

| startdate | starttime | endtime | timesheetid | servicestate | recordcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-30 00:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 09:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 13:00:00.000000 | 527915 | 2 | 1 |
| 2024-01-30 00:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 13:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 15:00:00.000000 | 527915 | 2 | 2 |
| 2024-01-30 00:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 14:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 15:00:00.000000 | 527915 | 2 | 1 |

What I'm trying to do is get distinct time ranges and the number of records for each range:

| startdate | starttime | endtime | timesheetid | servicestate | recordcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-30 00:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 09:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 13:00:00.000000 | 527915 | 2 | 1 |
| 2024-01-30 00:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 13:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 14:00:00.000000 | 527915 | 2 | 1 |
| 2024-01-30 00:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 14:00:00.000000 | 2024-01-30 15:00:00.000000 | 527915 | 2 | 2 |

I've gone done lot's of rabbit trails, but I haven't made any real progress to get there.

I'm stuck on postgresql 9.6 unfortunately.